# PHP & CSS: dynamically linking CSS using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Am trying to use PHP to dynamically attach same css sheet to different directory or different path on my site like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en-GB">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <?php
    if($pagename == 'login.php' || $pagename == 'register.php' || $pagename == 'admin_page.php'){?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <?php}else{?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <?php}
    ?>
    </head>
```

Its not working when I tried it, but I really want to know if its possible.

Right here itb says "unexpected end of file"

Comment: Where do you define `$pagename`? It doesn't seem to exist which would obviously cause this to fail.

Comment: inside each script e.g I defined $pagename = "login.php" inside the file "login.php"

Comment: I would use `in_array($pagename, [{list_of_pages}])` but that's not why it is not working.  Without knowing the value of `$pagename` it's impossible to know.

Comment: @Phoenix you mean I should create an array of all the pages inside the head tag?

Comment: You will need to show that code here as we have no way of knowing how that is done or if it is done properly

Comment: I will do that in the Answer textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(basename(__FILE__) == 'login.php' || basename(__FILE__) == 'register.php' || basename(__FILE__) == 'admin_page.php')
{//your link
}
```

should do the trick. If you need also a path, try `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`